# kotlin app crashes while running for facebook and instagram webviews

Tags: kotlin

```
 private lateinit var facebook:ImageView
    private lateinit var instagram:ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        facebook=findViewById(R.id.ivfacebook)
        instagram=findViewById(R.id.ivinstagram)
        facebook.setOnClickListener {
            openFacebookApp()
        }
        instagram.setOnClickListener {
            openInstagramApp()
        }
    }
    private fun openFacebookApp() {
        try {
            val uri=Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/")
            val facebook = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri)
            facebook.setPackage("com.facebook.android")
            startActivity(facebook)
        }catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException){
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/")))
        }
    }
    private fun openInstagramApp() {
        try {
            val uri = Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/")
            val instagram = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
            instagram.setPackage("com.instagram.android")
            startActivity(instagram)
        }catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException){
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/")))
        }
    }
```

i am writing this code for instagram and facebook webviews whenever user lick on instagram and facebook button the pages will open but this code properly work for instagram but when i write this for facebook app suddenly crashes

Comment: Please provide the stack trace from the crash.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.